# Numba GPU support for NVIDIA with compute capability 2.1

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I can't seem to understand the requirements for numba concerning cuda support. In here (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/overview.html) it states that I need compute capability higher than 2.0, I have an NVIDIA GeForce 820M which has 2.1, so I would think that's ok, but here (https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installing.html) it states that I need 3.0 or higher and even then it's discontinued. Plus, when I run "nvcc --version" from the command prompt I get

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Tue_May__3_19:00:59_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64 Build
> cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0

but I keep getting an error when running

```
from numba import cuda
gpu = cuda.get_current_device()
```

as:

> CudaDriverError: driver missing function: cuDeviceGetUuid. Requires
> CUDA 9.2 or above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first doc link points to numba 0.50, while your second link points to 0.55, which is likely going to be more relevant to your current Numba version. You can try downgrading numba to versions that still supported compute capability 2.1, but I wouldn't have high hopes here...

Comment: But how come I have CUDA 11.7 version installed and it still asks for a version higher than 9.2? Is it not the same thing?

Comment: Check your numba version using `import numba; print(numba.__version__)`. The problem most likely lies there.

Comment: Cuda version and CUDA compute capability are not the same thing. You need a compute capability 3.0 or greater GPU to make Numba work. You don't have that. There is no solution to your problem except use a different GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of confusion in this question, so let's break it down.

You have a very old GPU. So old that support for it was deprecated and removed from CUDA in 2017. No modern version of Numba will support it.

> In here (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/overview.html) it states that I need compute capability higher than 2.0

I don't think that Numba has ever actually supported compute 2.x devices. It relies on libnvvm (NVIDIA's lvvm to PTX compiler library) and that has only ever supported compute 3.x and newer devices, IIRC. But in any case, support for your GPU, if it existed, was removed from CUDA (and by extension Numba) a long time ago.

> when I run "nvcc --version" from the command prompt I get
>
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Tue_May__3_19:00:59_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64 Build
> cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
>
> but I keep getting an error when running

The nvcc version you have is unrelated to whether your GPU is supported, and whether Numba will work correctly. CUDA 11.7 doesn't support your GPU. CUDA 8.0 was the last CUDA release with compute 2.1 support, as far as I am aware.

> but I keep getting an error when running
>
> `from numba import cuda gpu = cuda.get_current_device()`
>
> as:
>
> CudaDriverError: driver missing function: cuDeviceGetUuid. Requires
> CUDA 9.2 or above.

This is because your very old GPU requires a very old driver family and that driver family can't support any functions added to CUDA after CUDA 9.0 was released. The Numba internals are telling you they failed to work because your driver is too old. But there is no newer driver for your GPU that will work.

In summary, you have an old GPU. It has no CUDA support. It has no Numba support (and probably never had any Numba support). Your only solution is to use a different GPU.